# Reflection of light

Tags: visible-light, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a white object and a mirror?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/what-is-the-difference-between-a-white-object-and-a-mirror)

When I look at a red object under white light, I see it as red because it absorbs the other colours and reflects the red light.

When I wear black clothes in summer, I get hotter than if I wear white clothes because the black absorbs all colours of light and the energy associated with it.

So my question is, what makes the difference between a white piece of paper and a mirror? The white paper doesn't absorb any colours, that's why it looks white. But what makes that different from a mirror, which also reflects the light that hits it?

Or is my basic understanding of light and colour wrong? I'm not exactly experienced in Physics, I just like knowing how some things work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1957/2451

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Probably would've found it if I could have given my question a better title. Ah well.

Comment: Yeah, probably. Something to keep in mind for future questions.