# What reflects/scatters sunlight most?

Tags: scattering, reflection

The difference between [a white object and a mirror](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1957) is mainly scattering versus reflection. If we neglect this difference and define the reflectivity by input energy minus transmitted energy minus absorbed energy, what is the material with the highest reflectivity?  With material, I mean something like [a single element mirror](http://www.optocity.com/mirror-metal.htm), any [multi-layer mix in a dielectric mirror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_mirror) or any sort of white-colored surface.

As the reflectivity depends on the wavelength, let's assume, our input energy is distributed according to the sun's spectrum (on the earth's ground). Let's further assume, there is no polarization. With these definitions, it should be possible to define a reflection coefficient as a scalar.

I am interested in theoretical aspects of the problem, laboratory results/examples and home-made solutions (alumium foil, wall color, etc)

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. Are you asking for the best known reflector of light with the solar spectrum?

Comment: @JohnRennie essentially yes, I am asking for the best known reflector as defined in the question. But as mentioned, I would also be grateful for some theoretical explanatations, and the performance of the best white and best mirroring material

Comment: That's a big question because absorption is determined by the band structure of the solid and also its defect states, while reflectivity is determined by the refractive index, which is in turn determined by the electronic structure. You're asking us to write you a several thousand word essay.

Comment: @JohnRennie: That's not my intention, sorry for being unprecise. I think the level of detail is important here. You already answered my question to some extent without needing several thousand words (thanks for that). Although I am new to physics.stackexchange, I think it's ok for stackexchange in general to give a high-level answer and optionally provide links for more details. But as I didn't found the links myself, I was asking the question here. I haven't read physical journals regarding this topic, though, as I usually deal with lower frequencies.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Regarding the physics in your comment: Isn't the band structure of the solid also determined by the electron structure? So doesn't absorption and reflectivity follow from the same root cause (electrons)? If that were true, I think one could reformulate my question into: What material should you take to have optimally arranged electrons for reflection?

Comment: See [Why does the refractive index depend on wavelength?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71126/why-does-the-refractive-index-depend-on-wavelength) for some background on the link between optical absorption and refractive index. Yes, they are connected, but not in any simple way.