# if white things reflect light and mirror reflect light why don't they look the same

Tags: optics, reflection

We learned at school that white object reflects all the light that falls on it. We also learned that a mirror reflects all light as well. However, we cannot see ourselves in a white object while we can see ourselves in a mirror.

What makes a mirror different from a white surface?

If both white surface and mirror reflect all the light that fall on them, then why don't they look the same?

Comment: Imagine a mirror, then break it into two pieces oriented in different directions. The image will be split in two. Repeat this process until you no longer notice a difference. The object is now white.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a white object and a mirror?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1957/)

Answer (score 1):

#### MIRROR

- The thing is that, A *mirror* is a **surface**  from which light get totally reflected.
- It have a polished surface. We generally see mirror effect from metal surface.
- The light which come in `strike` at angle $\theta$ to the normal and `reflect` away at  $\theta$ from the normal.

#### WHITE SURFACE

- It is a surface which seems to be white but it *reflect* and *disperse* of all seven *visible* wavelength.
- The surface is microscopically very rough. White surface are generally clothes, paints, non-metal, paper.
- The light which come in `strike` at angle $\theta$ to the normal and `reflect` away at many various angle from the normal.
- There is lot of distortion and dispersion of light.

That is why, a mirror $surface$ and white $surface$ are different.

Comment: I don't think dispersion of light means what you think it means.

Answer (score 0):

A white object only appears white if white light is striking it. If only red light is striking it, it appears red. A mirror has less distortion than other surfaces so it reflects light in a straight line. You don't see the surface of the mirror but rather the objects from which the light originates.

NB, when I speak about white or red light, it's important to remember that light itself has no colour. Colours are merely how our brains interpret different wavelengths.