# What causes impossible colors (supergreen) that can be represented on a gamut to not be visible to the eye?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Supergreen is a color with an RGB value of (0, 255, 0), making it fully green, with no other colors. Now, according to my research, it is impossible for the human eye to detect this color. Doing research, I found out that it is impossible for the photoreceptors in the eye to detect only *one* color; they have to detect multiple colors. For instance, when the eye detects green, it will also detect a little bit of red. Why is this?

Comment: I’ve displayed this color on a computer and had no trouble seeing it. I can also see super red and super blue. I suggest that you try it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If monochromatic light shines into our eyes, will that activate multiple types of cones or only one type of cone?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/556930/if-monochromatic-light-shines-into-our-eyes-will-that-activate-multiple-types-o) If not, please edit your question to say exactly what more we can explain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which RGB space are you talking about? The gamut of the common sRGB space is substantially smaller than the gamut of normal human vision, as shown by https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Cie_Chart_with_sRGB_gamut_by_spigget.png from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut#Visualization_of_gamuts

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/648786/123208

Comment: Note that (0,1,0) is also green-only, with no red or blue.